# Multi term query in Sphinx: Which term matched which result?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I am using Sphinx and I am doing multi term searches.

In the result array there is a 'matches' array, and a 'words' array, but I have no clue on how to link the both of them.

I.E: I search for "dance eat" and my result is "Dancing with bla bla". So I know that the matched term is "dance"... but I have no clue on how to make sphinx telling me that.

Have you any idea? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The resultset doesn't tell you that.

You can use the BuildExcerpts function to get some highlighting of the results. Viewing the excerpts shows which keywords match.

Edit: Prototype code...

```
$ids = array_keys($res["matches"]);
$stemmed_words = array_keys($res['words']);
$query_words = explode(' ',trim(preg_replace('/[^\w]+/',' ',$q)));

$docs = array();
foreach ($ids as $c => $id) {
    $docs[$c] = strip_tags($rows[$id]['body']);
}
$reply = $cl->BuildExcerpts($docs, $CONF['sphinx_index'], $q);

$matches = array();
foreach ($ids as $c => $id) {
    if (preg_match_all('/<b>(\w+)<\/b>/',$reply[$c],$m)) {
        $matches[$id] = array();
        foreach ($m[1] as $document_word) {
            $best_distance = 99999;
            $best_index = -1;
            foreach ($stemmed_words as $stemmed_index => $stemmed_word) {
                $distance = levenshtein(strtolower($document_word),$stemmed_word);
                if ($distance < $best_distance) {
                    $best_distance = $distance;
                    $best_index = $stemmed_index;
                }
            }
            if ($best_index > -1)
                $matches[$id][] = $query_words[$best_index];
        }
    }
}
```

The $matches array the contains a list of words that match each result.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it won't help me.
BuildExcerpts will bring me back something like this: 
"**Dancing** with bla bla" but won't bring "Dancing with bla bla" was match with "Dance"

Comment: Ah, yes good point. With morphology, its a bit more complicated. But still shouldnt be too difficult. Can take the words and find the one with the lowest levenstein distance?

Comment: With which morphology you might think it would be possible ? It sure sound very complicated to me :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer... It is nice, but I won't be able to use it their... I have too many answers and too many keywords to check. 
I was looking for a sphinx feature that just doesn't exists. It sucks badly! But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be something like BuildKeywords but you still miss the ids :

```
[0] => Array
        (
                [tokenized] => keyword1
                [normalized] => p5162
                [docs] => 3
                [hits] => 7
        )

[1] => Array
        (
                [tokenized] => keyword2
                [normalized] => m340
                [docs] => 15
                [hits] => 23
        )
```

^
Maybe there is a way to get the [docs] ids ?

Comment: That's exactly my question! Is there a way to get the [docs] ids ?